# How to parse a json response in Objective C.

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I am really stuck right now and am looking for some help.

I am stuck trying to parse this from JSON into Objective C. I have no idea what it is.

dates: (
    "2017-05-11",
    "2017-05-14",
    "2017-05-22",
    "2017-05-28"
)

Is this an array? And if so, how do I parse it?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like debug output of an array, but it is not a valid JSON array

Comment: Please show what you have tried (code).

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Where is this data coming from?